# Codeigniter + Biostall's Google Maps API v3 : Different InfoWindow in different Markers

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

While i was looking for a solution on how to geocode the addresses in my database, i stumbled upon this library by Biostall, its a Google Map integrated in CodeIgniter. My problem now is, on the docs, there's this parameter under the markers that sets its onclick js.

```
$marker['onclick'] = "";
```

Now i am stuck in this part. Is it going to be just a standard JS? or is there another way? I have tried doing this, but to no avail, it won't work.

```
$marker['onclick'] = `infowindow.open(map, marker);

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
 });

 var contentString = "<div>HELLO WORLD!</div>" `;
```

Any tips will do! I'm not really knowledgeable with Javascript, and would really appreciate any help i can get.

Comment: Move the assignment of contentString before creating the InfoWindow instance. And then add click listener like this:

        **$marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });**

Comment: BTW, here is a sample from Google itself: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

Comment: Thank you! But i solved it. There's a parameter in the docs that sets the infoWindow content. I just placed the info window there, and call it on the onclick parameter. But thank you!

Comment: Great that you managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while scanning through the documentation, i found a parameter called 'infowindow_content'.

```
$marker['infowindow_content'] = "//insert info window content here. :D";
```

EDIT: So, no need to use the $marker['onclick'] = ''; if you are going to use the ['infowindow_content']. It automatically implements to every markers (if your addresses comes from your database).

E.G:

$marker['infowindow_content'] = 'Name: '.$dbres->fname.','.$dbres->lname;

Its result when you click a marker will be:

Name: First Name, Last name.